# PHP foreach() not looping through data as expected?

Tags: php, foreach

I have the foillowing PHP code, but I can't get it to work?

This is the main PHP file:

```
function get_data() {
$query = 'SELECT title, article FROM submissions';
$result = mysql_query($query);

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
++$i;

$row['i'] = $i;

$row['title'] = limittext($row['title'], 15);

}
return $row; //perhaps because $row is not return all?

}

$data = get_data();

require('template/data.inc.php');

?>
```

and this is template/data.inc.php:

```
<?php

foreach ($data as $value):

echo $data['i'].'<br>';

echo $data['title'].'<br>';

echo $data['article'].'<br>';

endforeach;

?>
```

template/data.inc.php is meant to output something like:

```
1 How to get your site on Google?
Text... 
2 Secrets of SEO Revealed
Text...
```

My guess is get_data() is not returning the array() in a form which is supported within the foreach? - as its currently giving an error.

Comment: Define "not working" please. Post a sample output of your `get_data()` function ...

Comment: btw, if you're really a 'newbtophp' some friendly advice: ditch the mysql_ family of functions, and use either mysqli (new and improved!) or PDO.

Comment: And get yourself a good IDE (for instance  [Eclipse PDT](https://eclipse.org/pdt/)) and learn how to set a breakpoint and evaluate variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
++$i;

$row['i'] = $i;

$row['title'] = limittext($row['title'], 15);

}
```

On every iteration, `$row` is being reset to current record, and in the end `mysql_fetch_assoc` will turn it to `FALSE`. You have to put each `$row` into auxiliary array and return it as whole resultset:

```
$i = 0;
$returnArray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
++$i;
$row['i'] = $i;
$row['title'] = limittext($row['title'], 15);
$returnArray[] = $row;
}

return $returnArray;
```

ANd in your template use `$value` to get details for each row:

```
foreach ($data as $value):
echo $value['i'].'<br>';
echo $value['title'].'<br>';
echo $value['article'].'<br>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: technically, wouldn't the last iteration be false (so it breaks out of the loop). +1 for the answer

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, however I'm getting an error? - 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:/xampplite/htdocs/template/data.inc.php on line 18

Comment: @DTest: tht's TRUE ;) I corrected my answer, thanks!. @newtophp: can you put `var_dump($data);die;` after `$data = get_data();` and post result in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you're building $row and returning it

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ++$i;

    $row['i'] = $i;

    $row['title'] = limittext($row['title'], 15);

    }
    return $row;
}
```

You'll only EVER have the LAST iteration of $row set ... if that's what you want? In other words, $row will only continue a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop continues until $row has an value that is evaluated as false:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

and then you return $row so you always return null or false!

replace

```
$row['title'] = limittext($row['title'], 15);
```

with

```
$row['title'] = limittext($row['title'], 15);
$result[]=$row;
```

and

```
return $row;
```

with

```
return $result;
```